# Cocoa, store class to call class methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i would like to store and set a class variable, so i can call its class methods

is smth. similar like this possible?

```
Class classInstance = [someInstance class];

[classInstance callSomeClassMethod]; // declared with +, like + (void)callSomeClassMethod
```

Comment: Considering you have pretty much written the right code above - did you not think to just run it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible...

```
Class klass = [NSString class];

NSLog(@"%@", [[klass alloc] initWithUTF8String:"hey"]);

//=> 2012-07-26 17:29:56.882 Untitled 4[4061:707] hey
```

Comment: but doesnt seems to work with core data items

Comment: care to elaborate on what doesn't work?